# php image show issu

Tags: php, mysql

I've a html form box where i can post subject, image and message. if i post a article without image it's show a image box. I don't want the image box. If i post a article without image then it's should be show only subject and message not image box. But It's show a image box with blank box.

So that i use following sql query but nothing happened...

```
$no_img = mysql_query("SELECT img_name FROM user_post WHERE post_id = '$id'");
$no_img_check = mysql_num_rows($no_img);

if($no_img_check != 0)
{
echo '<a href="blogpost.php?post_id= ' . $id . '&title=' . $sub. ' "><img src="' . 
$upload_path . '/' . $imgname . '" width="140" height="105" alt="NO iamge"  
/></a>';        
}
else
{
echo "NO image";
}
```

Any Idea...

Comment: Would you mind dumping your variables and seeing if they are indeed set? Thanks.

Comment: Just before your 3rd line add *echo $no_img_check;* let us know what result you are getting when no_img is true...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the only case when you would get 0 rows is when the userid doesn't match in the database.  If the userid is in the database, but there is no image, you would get a non-zero number of results where each result was either a NULL or an empty string (depending on your DB default value for that column).

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting `$imgname` anywhere. You've only performed a query (`SELECT img_name FROM...`) but haven't actually retrieved that value from the database (i.e. you have a result `$no_img` but nothing in your code suggests that you've set `$imgname`). Use `mysql_fetch_array()` or similar to actually get that value.